# JavaScript function declared outside addEventListener does not work

Tags: javascript

I tried to declare a function and reuse it in a few addEventListeners in JavaScript, however when I do that, the whole function does not work. On the other hand, when I use the same code making anonymous functions, everything is okay. This is the code that doesn't do the job:

```
damianImg.addEventListener("mouseover", imageChanging());
damianImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", imageChanging());

function imageChanging(){
if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian2.jpg");
} else if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian2.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian3.jpg");
} else {
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian.jpg");
}
}
```

And here is a piece of code that works:

```
damianImg.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian2.jpg");
} else if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian2.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian3.jpg");
} else {
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian.jpg");
}
})

damianImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian2.jpg");
} else if(damianImg.src.indexOf("media/damian2.jpg") != -1){
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian3.jpg");
} else {
    damianImg.src = ("media/damian.jpg");
}
})
```

Where is an error or why is it not possible to use an external function? I also wanted to make a function that would take parameters so I could use it for different pictures but for now even in this simple case it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the function without calling it, otherwise you're passing the returned value of `imageChanging` which is `undefined`.

```
damianImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", imageChanging);
```

If you want to use a function that takes parameters, you can pass parameters to `imageChanging` and return a function.

```
function click(label) {

    return function() {
        console.log(`[${label}] click`)
    }
}

damianImg.addEventListener('click', click('damian'));
fooImg.addEventListener('click', click('foo'));
```

You can also use `.bind` to pass arguments.

```
function click(label, event) {
    console.log(`[${label}] click`)
}

damianImg.addEventListener('click', click.bind(damianImg, 'damian'));
fooImg.addEventListener('click', click.bind(fooImg, 'foo'));
```

Or just wrap it in a function and call `imageChanging`

```
damianImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => imageChanging('argument'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that! What if I want to pass a parameter but don't want to get the returned value? When I change the damianImg to img (a new parameter of imageChanging) and pass it in damianImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", imageChanging(damianImg)) it doesn't work again...

Comment: Thank you for your full answer, it's really helpful!

Comment: Instead of having it return a function, it would probably be much cleaner to just wrap the call to `imageChanging` in a function at the call site. That function shouldn't care how it's used. If you want to use the function for another purpose later, now you need to call it twice.

Comment: There are multiple patterns possible. I disagree that returning a function isn't clean. It's a pattern widely used in express middlewares and other frameworks, and I find it quite powerful & clean.